# Changing autoGenerating Grails Test Scaffold to Spock Test

Tags: grails, spock

Hi i m trying to change the auto-generated testCases in grails

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class KLAKSpec {

    void setUp() {
        // Setup logic here
    }

    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    void testSomething() {
        fail "Implement me"
    }
}
```

to Spock Type test format which is something like this

```
@TestFor(GrailsUnitTestCase)
class @artifact.name@ extends @artifact.superclass@ {
        def "feature method"() {
                setup:


                when:


                then:


                where:

}
}
```

Althought i have added a _Events.groovy script under the scipt folder and added a Spec.groovy file in artifacts folder which changes the name when i auto generate the list.

Can any one please let me knw how i can change to spec format.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on this some time ago: [Auto-generate Spock specs for Grails artifacts](http://adhockery.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/auto-generate-spock-specs-for-grails.html). The post was written pre-Grails 2 so it's still using the old superclasses rather than `@TestFor` but it should be easy enough to adapt. We still use this technique on our project where we're still on Grails 1.3.7. It's a bit of a blunt instrument as Grails doesn't expose a unique event for test generation but it works fine.